# Save dict to JSON in correct order, failing

Tags: python, json

Why does this happen? In Python. I am reading and saving to it. Is there a way to control how JSON is saved? I only know 'utf-8' and that you should read or write to the file.

**This is what I get:**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "result": {
                "2": 66,
                "0": 22,
                "1": 34
            },
            "name": "Amanda"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is what I want:**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Amanda",
            "result": {
                "0": 22,
                "1": 34,
                "2": 66
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So you want some elements to be removed? The only difference I see between both examples are the missing entries for `Patrik` and `Oscar`.

Comment: That is the most incomprehensible question I've seen. Probably because I only know ASCII.

Comment: No really. I excluded the other to, to avoid filling up the page with to much. Let me edit and clarify that.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, regardless of how you feel or see things around here. I cannot understand that even if I make the file correctly manually and tell python to print it out, it seems so different.

Comment: Why do you need it to be sorted? JSON is key-value format (dictionary). So it is unordered. And it has nothing to do with UTF-8 and reading and writing to the file.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. This is true in Python as well as in Javascript. If you need ordering, use a list.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, Yeah I know it has zero to do with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all it takes was: `sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':')`

Comment: this is good, but you should enhance your answer, it is a bit terse.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

- iterate through the original dictionary
- convert each sub-dictionary to an `OrderedDict` and create a list of them, sorting the keys so `name` is before `result` (if this is the order you want, else, something else can be done to order the keys, or hardcode them)
- dump the structure with list of ordered dictionaries

my code (`jd` is your structure):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_list = []
for x in jd["results"]:
    ordered = OrderedDict()
    for k,v in sorted(x.items()):
        ordered[k] = v
    ordered_list.append(ordered)

print(json.dumps({"results" : ordered_list}))
```

result:

```
{"results": [{"name": "Amanda", "result": {"0": 22, "2": 66, "1": 34}}]}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, for this.

Comment: Why does this not order other results I add with other names?